# Angular 6 router.events.filter 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have finished to update my App to Angular 6 (it was in 5.2 version).

I got an error syntax in :

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
constructor(private router: Router) {}

this.router.events.filter
      (event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe((res) => 
    {
      // DO something
    });
```

> error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'.

what's the right syntax in Angular 6 ?

thanks

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'

Comment: I use RXJS 6:  import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This is how to filter router events with Angular 6+ and latest RxJS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe(() => {
            console.log(this.activatedRoute.root);
        });
    }
}
```

Uses the `pipe` operator instead of attempting to chain filter on the observable.

Comment: This works for RxjS 6 with a new required operator pipe. For RxJS 5, you could refer to @ritaj's comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Lansana! I upgraded to 6 and my service stopped working.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to access that event's url property, I am not able to access it

Comment: @Hope Try `console.log(...)` on the event object and see what properties you have access to.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see in your code if you imported filter

for Rxjs 6:

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

    .
    .
    .

     this.router.events.pipe(
       filter((event:Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
     ).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

Activated Route wasnt giving me the url. So I tried this.
P.S: event['url'] worked instead of event.url

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router,NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

 router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .subscribe(event => 
         {
            this.currentRoute = event['url'];          
            console.log(this.currentRoute);
         });
```