# url property of NavigationEnd returns undefined (Angular 6)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, router

I'm relatively new to front-end stuff, I was playing around with Angular 6, so the issue I'm facing with the following component is that [NavigationEnd](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd) returns *undefined* and I can't figure out why:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(
      (navEnd: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = navEnd.url
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "*NavigationEnd returns undefined*"?

Comment: Pretty sure router.events has more than just NavigationEnd events; https://angular.io/api/router/Event

Comment: @user184994 Oops sorry...

Comment: Take note of the point raised by @Jusmpty and have  a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353164/angular-6-router-events-filter-filter-does-not-exist-on-type-observableevent) for a solution

Comment: @user184994 sure..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[`router.events`](https://angular.io/api/router/Event)** has different events, if you need to get the NavigationEnd you need to filter as follows. Try this,

```
 router.events
      .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((e: NavigationEnd) => {
        this.currentUrl = e.url;       
 });
```

Comment: Not working for me, getting the following error "Argument of type '(e: NavigationEnd) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Event_2) => void' "

Answer (score 2):

You need to check which type of events you receive from the subscribe method.

Also you need to use `this` to access router ( it's a private variable)

```
 constructor(private router: Router) {
this.router.events
  .subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.currentUrl = event.url
      console.log('NavigationEnd:', event);
    }
  })
```

Comment: You don't need "this" inside the constructor to access router

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to achive is the following.

```
this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => this.activatedRoute)
 ).subscribe((event) => {
       this.currentUrl = event.url
});
```

Inject ActivatedRoute in the constructor.

Comment: If you're mapping each `NavigationEnd` event into an `ActivatedRoute`, bear in mind that `ActivatedRoute.url` is an `Observable`, not a string

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this in async, for checking a condition,

```
async getUrl(){
    this._router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((path:NavigationEnd)=>{
    console.log("path",path);  
    this.activeUrl=path.url.split('/');
    this.activeUrl.splice(0,1)
    console.log("activeurl",this.activeUrl);
    return this.activeUrl;
    })
}
this.getUrl().then(()=>{
    if(this.activeUrl[1]=='admin'){
    //your code goes here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix,

change the code

```
(navEnd: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = navEnd.url
```

to

```
(navEnd: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = router.url
```

Comment: this will not update the url whenever the navigationEnd event fires.

Answer (score -1):

Just one line change required to make it work on Angular 7

```
router.events.subscribe(() => this.currentUrl = this.router.url)
```