# Hide header on specif route - angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to hide the header, only in one route.

Let's say that I've three routes, `route1`, `route2` and `route3`.

And I've one component called `app-header`.

I want the component `app-header` to be hidden when the user enters in the `route1` and show this component in the other 2 routes.

I've found some topics here on stackoverflow, but none of them helped me =/

Can you guys give me some help with that?

Here's my code:

- **app.component.ts**

  ```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      showHeader = true;

      constructor(
          private router: Router
      ) {
          this.router.events.subscribe(event => this.modifyHeader(event));
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      modifyHeader(location) { // This method is called many times
          console.log(location.url); // This prints a loot of routes on console
          if (location.url === '/route1') {
              this.showHeader = false;
          } else {
              this.showHeader = true;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  - **app.component.html**

    ```
    <app-header *ngIf="showHeader"></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    ```

I'm using angular `6.1.4`

Comment: Try to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50353265/356380

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you know which route you want to detect, and seem to have a solution in the app component in mind, I'd suggest filtering the router events, as such:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    showHeader = true;

    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) {
        this.router.events.pipe(
            filter(e => e instanceOf NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe(event => this.modifyHeader(event));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    modifyHeader(location) { // This method is called many times
        console.log(location.url); // This prints a loot of routes on console
        if (location.url === '/route1') {
            this.showHeader = false;
        } else {
            this.showHeader = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arne, this solution worked, I just needed to do the import of filter `import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 2):

Add function on router outlet

```
<router-outlet  (activate)="modifyHeader()"></router-outlet>
```

In your constructor

```
router; 
constructor(private _router: Router ) {
      this.router = _router;
    }
```

Your modifyHeader function

```
modifyHeader() { // This method is called many times
        console.log(this.router.ur); // This prints a loot of routes on console
        if (this.router.ur === '/route1') {
            this.showHeader = false;
        } else {
            this.showHeader = true;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Krishna's solution is really performance friendly as this observable can't be unsubscribed of, because it is in the root AppComponent of the app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33581895)